# Python to C# Dictionary

Tags: python, c#

I'm trying to convert some python code into C#. The python code uses a dictionary structure and I've created a similar object in C#. I'm hoping to get help on a specific section:

```
'''
letterHTMLTemplates = {}
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select lower(cast([id] as nvarchar(36))) as [id], [template] from dbo. 
[lookup.letter]")
for row in cursor:
    letterHTMLTemplates.update( {row.id : str(row.template)} )    
# Replace the <head> tag in all letters, as it contains the confetti nonsense
for letterKey in letterHTMLTemplates:
    startHead = letterHTMLTemplates[letterKey].find("<head>")
    endHead = letterHTMLTemplates[letterKey].find("</head>") + len("</head>")
    beforeHead = letterHTMLTemplates[letterKey][:startHead]
    endHead = letterHTMLTemplates[letterKey][endHead:]
    newHead = '<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>' # Replace the head with this - necessary to render weird characters
    letterHTMLTemplates[letterKey] = beforeHead + newHead + endHead
```

'''
I've written this so far in C# but I'm having trouble with the the find part in C#:

```
    '''
    public static void parseSlateDocs()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetSlateConnectionString());
        string query = "select lower(cast([id] as nvarchar(36))) as [id], [template] from dbo.[lookup.letter]";
        Dictionary<int, string> letterTemplate = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn))
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    foreach(KeyValuePair<int,string> kvp in letterTemplate)
                    {
                        letterTemplate.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                        //find the "<head>" tag
                }
            }
        }
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need  IndexOf(string str) method:

```
string str = "Hello Friends....How are you..."; 
  
        int i = str.IndexOf("How"); 
  
        // As this string is present in the  
        // main string then it will obviously 
        //  output the value as 17 
        Console.WriteLine("First value Index of 'How' is " + i); 
  
        // now the following string is not present 
        // So as per the rules, it will return -1 
        int i1 = str.IndexOf("Chair"); 
  
        // As this string is present in  
        // the main string then it will  
        // obviously output the value as -1 
        Console.WriteLine("First value Index of 'Chair' is " + i1);
```

Use this method to find head.
Example from  GeeksForGeeks.

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason why I couldn't use a data table or data set instead of a dictionary?

Comment: It would be better to work with objects and collections. Your code will be more maintainable/readable, composable , testable & reusable.A generic collection is potentially MUCH more lightweight than a DataTable.